# Dynamic allocation of 'string' arrays

Tags: c++, string, dynamic-allocation

I tried this

```
string *codes = (string*)malloc(256*sizeof(string));
codes[0] = "";
```

in C++. But it didn't work, but when I tried

```
string *codes = new string[256];
codes[0] = "";
```

This worked.
I did not understand the basic idea behind why this is happening. Could someone please tell me.

Thanks

Comment: Use std::vector<std::string>>

Answer (score 3):

This is because `new` uses constructor of the given class (in your case: `std::string`) and `malloc()` doesn't do this.